# What would the equivalent button_to call of this link_to usage be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to call that works as expected:

```
<%= link_to "Freeze", url_for([user, status: :frozen]), method: :put %>
# Generates: <a href="/users/1?status=frozen" rel="nofollow" data-method="put">Freeze</a>
```

But I've read I should instead use button_to for updating resources because it generates the important-looking "authenticity_token" and defaults to POST method.

How would I write a button_to call that functions the same as the above link_to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
<%= 
  button_to(
    "Freeze",
    user,
    method: :put,
    params: { status: :frozen }
  )
%>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! ^_^